# When I was training the multivariate time series with existing models like astgcn, I write my own train procedure, but result seems so bad

Tags: time-series, training-data

I want to reproduce several multivariate time series models, I wrote my own training functions instead of that from their github websites. However, my training seems to get converged fast at one or two steps, and have a bad result.

This is the train.py

```
import torch 
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import numpy as np
import logging
from src.model.rnn_gcn import RNN_GCN
from src.data_iterator import DataIterator
from src.utils import plot
import torch.nn as nn
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, configs, model: RNN_GCN, train_iterator, val_iterator, test_iterator, is_eval=False):
        self.configs = configs
        self.device = configs['device']
        self.model = model
        self.model = self.model.to(self.device)
        self.horizon = configs['horizon']
        self.window_size = configs['window_size']

        self.scaler = train_iterator.get_scaler().to(self.device)
        self.networks = train_iterator.get_networks()
        for i in range(len(self.networks)):
            self.networks[i] = self.networks[i].to(self.device)
        if self.configs['optimizer'] == 'Adam':
            self.opt = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=configs['lr'])
        elif self.configs['optimizer'] == 'SGD':
            self.opt = torch.optim.SGD(self.model.parameters(), lr=configs['lr'], momentum=0.9)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Optimizer not implemented')
        
        self.train_iterator = train_iterator.get_loader()
        self.val_iterator = val_iterator.get_loader()
        self.test_iterator = test_iterator.get_loader()
        self.loss_min = np.inf
        self.n_tolerance = 0

        if not os.path.exists(self.configs["save_dir"]):
            os.makedirs(self.configs["save_dir"])
        
        if is_eval:
            self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join(self.configs['save_dir'], self.configs['model_name'])))
        
    
    def train(self):
        for epoch in range(self.configs['epochs']):
            self._train_epoch(epoch)
            eval_loss = self.eval()
            if eval_loss < self.loss_min:
                self.loss_min = eval_loss
                self.n_tolerance = 0
                self.best_model = self.model.state_dict()
            else:
                self.n_tolerance += 1
                if self.n_tolerance >= self.configs['tolerance']:
                    logger.info('Early stopping at epoch {}'.format(epoch))
                    break
        logger.info('Training finished')

        self.model.load_state_dict(self.best_model)
        test_loss = self.test()
        torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), os.path.join(self.configs['save_dir'], f'model_{test_loss}.pt'))
    
    def _train_epoch(self, epoch):
        self.model.train()
        epoch_loss = 0
        n_iter = 0
        for values, indicators_train in tqdm(self.train_iterator):
            values = values.to(self.device)
            indicators_train = indicators_train.to(self.device)

            self.opt.zero_grad()
            y_pred = self._iter(values=values, epoch=epoch)
            y = values[..., -self.horizon:]
            indicators_y = indicators_train[..., -self.horizon:]
            y = (y + self.scaler[0]) * self.scaler[1]
            y_pred = (y_pred + self.scaler[0][...,0,:]) * self.scaler[1][...,0,:]
            iter_loss = self.get_rmse(y=y[...,0,:], y_pred=y_pred, indicators=indicators_y[...,0,:])
            iter_loss.backward()
            self.opt.step()

            n_iter += 1
            epoch_loss += iter_loss.item()
        epoch_loss /= n_iter
        logger.info("Epoch: {}, Loss: {}".format(epoch, epoch_loss))
        return epoch_loss

    def _iter(self, values, epoch=0):
        y_pred = self.model(values[..., :-self.horizon], self.networks, epoch=epoch)
        return y_pred

    def eval(self):
        self.model.eval()
        y_preds = []
        y_trues = []
        indicators = []
        for values, indicators_eval in tqdm(self.val_iterator):
            values = values.to(self.device)
            indicators_eval = indicators_eval.to(self.device)
            indicators_y = indicators_eval[..., -self.horizon:]
            y_pred = self._iter(values=values)
            y_preds.append(y_pred.detach().cpu())
            y_trues.append(values[...,-self.horizon:].detach().cpu())
            indicators.append(indicators_y.detach().cpu())
        indicators = torch.cat(indicators, axis=0)
        y_preds = torch.cat(y_preds, axis=0)
        y_trues = torch.cat(y_trues, axis=0)
        y_preds = (y_preds + self.scaler[0][...,0,:].cpu()) * self.scaler[1][...,0,:].cpu()
        y_trues = (y_trues + self.scaler[0].cpu()) * self.scaler[1].cpu()
        loss = self.get_rmse(y=y_trues[...,0,:], y_pred=y_preds, indicators=indicators[...,0,:])
        logger.info("Eval loss: {}".format(loss))
        return loss
    
    def test(self):
        self.model.eval()
        y_preds = []
        y_trues = []
        indicators = []
        for values, indicators_test in tqdm(self.test_iterator):
            values = values.to(self.device)
            indicators_test = indicators_test.to(self.device)
            indicators_y = indicators_test[..., -self.horizon:]
            y_pred = self._iter(values=values)
            y_preds.append(y_pred.detach().cpu())
            y_trues.append(values[..., -self.horizon:].detach().cpu())
            indicators.append(indicators_y.detach().cpu())
        y_preds = torch.cat(y_preds, axis=0)
        indicators = torch.cat(indicators, axis=0)
        y_trues = torch.cat(y_trues, axis=0)
        plot(y_trues=y_trues, y_preds=y_preds, mutli=False, plant=0)
        y_preds = (y_preds + self.scaler[0][...,0,:].cpu()) * self.scaler[1][...,0,:].cpu()
        y_trues = (y_trues + self.scaler[0].cpu()) * self.scaler[1].cpu()

        loss = self.get_rmse(y=y_trues[...,0,:], y_pred=y_preds, indicators=indicators[...,0,:])
        logger.info("Test loss: {}".format(loss))

        return loss
    
    def get_loss(self, y, y_pred, indicators):
        return nn.MSELoss()(y, y_pred)
    
    def get_mae(self, y, y_pred, indicators):
        return torch.mean(torch.abs(y - y_pred))
    
    def get_rmse(self, y, y_pred, indicators):
        return torch.sqrt(self.mse(y=y, y_pred=y_pred, indicators=indicators))

    def mse(self, y, y_pred, indicators):
        # calculate mse
        loss = (y - y_pred)**2
        # mask loss
        loss = torch.where(indicators == 1, loss, 0)
        n_points = torch.sum(indicators)
        loss = torch.sum(loss) / n_points
        return loss
```

other files are main.py, utils.py(including data preprocessing), data_iterator.py.
utils.py:

```
def data_prepare(configs):
    data_root = configs['data_root']
    values_name = configs['values_name']
    networks_name = configs['networks_name']
    indicators_name = configs['indicators_name']

    with open(os.path.join(data_root, values_name), 'rb') as f:
        values = pickle.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(data_root, networks_name), 'rb') as f:
        networks = pickle.load(f)
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(data_root, indicators_name), 'rb') as f:
            indicators = pickle.load(f)
    except:
        indicators = np.ones_like(values)

    split_ratio = configs['split_ratio']
    train_ratio = split_ratio[0]
    val_ratio = split_ratio[0] + split_ratio[1]

    window_size = configs['window_size']

    train_start_ends = [np.arange(i,i+window_size) for i in range(0, int(values.shape[-1]*train_ratio)-window_size)]
    val_start_ends = [np.arange(i,i+window_size) for i in range(int(values.shape[-1]*train_ratio)-window_size, int(values.shape[-1]*val_ratio)-window_size)]
    test_start_ends = [np.arange(i,i+window_size) for i in range(int(values.shape[-1]*val_ratio)-window_size, values.shape[-1]-window_size)]

    train_values = values[..., train_start_ends].astype(np.float32)
    train_indicators = indicators[..., train_start_ends]
    val_values = values[..., val_start_ends].astype(np.float32)
    val_indicators = indicators[..., val_start_ends]
    test_values = values[..., test_start_ends].astype(np.float32)
    test_indicators = indicators[..., test_start_ends]

    # get mean of train_values
    train_values, val_values, test_values, scaler = normalize(train_values, val_values, test_values)

    return train_values, train_indicators, val_values, val_indicators, test_values, test_indicators, scaler, networks


def normalize(train_values, val_values, test_values):
    mean = np.mean(train_values, axis=(0,2,3), keepdims=True)
    std = np.std(train_values, axis=(0,2,3), keepdims=True)
    train_values = (train_values - mean) / std
    val_values = (val_values - mean) / std
    test_values = (test_values - mean) / std
    return train_values, val_values, test_values, (mean, std)
```

I have tried to use several different data, so it could not be the problem of the input. It just  cannot match the original result.